# access facebook application from non admin account not work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have downloaded an example of Facebook Application using PHP sdk, and it is working well when I access it from the account that admin that application but when I try to access it from another account I got an error message

please any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Sandbox Mode for the app on https://developers.facebook.com

[image]

This restricts the application to developers.